# Natural permutation representations of the orthogonal group of a lattice

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

Let $A\in M_n(\Bbb Z)$ be a positive definite matrix so it gives a metric on $\Bbb Z^n$. Let $G=O(q,\Bbb Z^n)$ be the subgroup of $GL_n(\Bbb Z)$ preserving the metric. For every positive integer $d$, $G$ acts on $X_d=\{x\in\Bbb Z^n |\langle x,x\rangle =d\}$, which gives a complex reprensentation $\rho_d$ of $G$.

$G$ is a finite group as $A>0$, let $\rho_d=\bigoplus_{} m_d(V)V$ where $V$ runs through all irreducible representations of $G$. My interest lies in understanding those multiplicities when $d$ grows.

**Q1**. For any $V$, does there exist (infinitely many?) $d$ such that $m_d(V)>0$?

**Q2**. For which $V$, $\text{sup}_{d>0} m_d(V)=+\infty$?

**Q3**. If we don't require $A>0$, then is $G$ finitely generated? can we still talk about $m_d(V)$ ?

Example: $q(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ then $G\cong D_4$, by computation one could show that $m_d(V)=\frac{\#X_d}{r\operatorname{dim} V}+O(1)$ where $r$ is the number of irreducible representations of $G$.

Motivation: for $g \in G$, $Tr_{\rho_d}(g)=\# X_d \cap \operatorname{Ker}(g-id)$ can be regard as intersection number of $X_d$ and a linear subspace.

Edit: For example, what about the action on the $E_8$ lattice?

Comment: What is $\rho_d$? the representation associated to the given permutation action? (that is, the representation on $\mathbf{C}^{X_d}$)?

Comment: "If we don't assume $A>0$" is quite a vague hypothesis. Is $A$ an arbitrary matrix in $M_n(\mathbf{Z})$? symmetric? non-negative?

Comment: Yes, I mean the permutation representation. In general you could assume $A$ is symmetric or regard it as a quadratic form.

Comment: Q3: yep: $G$ is finitely generated; it is an arithmetic lattice in $O(q)(\mathbf{R})$ by Borel-Harish-Chandra. Since $X_d$ is likely to be infinite, the decomposition of the permutation representation is possibly not discrete.